# How to insert data from one column into another column in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables LESSON & SPORT.

LESSONNO | SPORTNO | INSTRUCTORNO | DATE | PRICE |

SPORTNO | SPORT NAME | SPORTDESCRIPTION |

I need to add column SPORTNAME to the lesson table, and for its data to match the SPORTNO in lesson table as it does in sport table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
ALTER TABLE LESSON ADD SPORTNAME VARCHAR(30); // or whatever type it is
UPDATE LESSON l JOIN SPORT s USING(SPORTNO) SET l.SPORTNAME = s.SPORTNAME;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in SQL Server

```
 ALTER TABLE LESSON ADD SPORTNAME VARCHAR(50)

  UPDATE LESSON
  SET SPORTNAME = S.SPORTNAME
  FROM dbo.LESSON AS L
  INNER JOIN dbo.SPORT AS S
  ON L.SPORTNO = S.SPORTNO
```

Hope it helps!